# How to get Formik NextJS Post Request to work?

Tags: axios, next.js, formik, chakra-ui

This is the relavant code:

```
 const handleSubmit = async (event, values, actions) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post(url, payload(values.name))
        .then(res => {
          // do stuff
        }).catch(err => {
          // do other stuff
    })
  }

  return (

      <Formik
          initialValues={{ name: 'Passwort' }}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(e, values, actions)}
        >
        {(props) => (
        ..
```

It really does not like my way of passing in e in order to prevent default.

This was default Formik code, which worked. However then how to prevent default?

```
   <Formik
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {

          // prevent default?

          axios.post(url, payload(values.name))
            .then(res => {
              // do  stuff
            }).catch(err => {
              // do other stuff
            })
        }
      }
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way by passing in Formik functions right after the last code snippet above  `{({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values}) => (`

This is described here: https://formik.org/docs/guides/react-native

I wonder however why no preventDefault needs to be coded into the solution, so this means Formik is Handling the default submit action. Unfortunately now this is not working anymore as a button prop:  `isLoading={values.isSubmitting}`